# Where can I see the version of Itunes that is installed?

Tags: macos, itunes

Most devs will place an 'About' tab in their 'Help' menu to allow users to see which version of software they are using. For some reason this is not the case with Itunes.

Could anyone please tell me where I can find the version of the currently installed Itunes app on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard macOS behaviour is to put the About… menu item in the first slot under the (App Name) menu, never in the Help menu.

iTunes is no different.

[image]

The Help menu is actually for Help, unlike most Windows apps ;)

[image]